# Kotlin error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()'

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this problem when I call this function validateCertificate() I've looked for everything and nothing works for me.

The error occurenci in this line => Gsurf( this ).inicializeGsurf()

class CardTransactionUseCase(call: MethodCall): AppCompatActivity() {

```
private var salefinished = false
private lateinit var textValue: String

private val gson = Gson()
private lateinit var params: Params
private var methodCallled: MethodCall = call

// validacao do certificado
fun validateCertificate() {

    Log.i("validatecertificate => ", "Caiu no validate")
    Log.i("Gsurf( this ) => ", "Gsurf( this ) => ${Gsurf( this ).application}")

    Gsurf( this ).inicializeGsurf().observe(this) {
        Log.i("validatecertificate => ", "${it.code} - ${it.message}")
        when ( it!!.code ) {
            200 -> {
                Log.i("validateCertificate", "${it.code} -- ${it.message}")
                createTransaction()
            }
            400 -> {
                Log.i("validateCertificate", "${it.code} -- ${it.message}")
                validateResponseRsa(it.code, it.message)
            }
            422 -> createCertificate()
        }
    }
}
```

}

here are the logs error

E/MethodChannel#project: Failed to handle method call
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:128)

at gsurfnet.sc3androidclient.libgsurf.gsurf.Gsurf.inicializeGsurf(Gsurf.kt:11)

at project.validateCertificate(CardTransactionUseCase.kt:32)

Comment: `CardTransactionUseCase` should not be an `AppCompatActivity`. Remove `: AppCompatActivity()`, and pass the necessary `Context` through a constuctor or function parameter. For example, `class CardTransactionUseCase(call: MethodCall, val context: Context)`, then use that `context` where needed.

Answer (score 1):

`Gsurf` needs a `Context`, which you're probably trying to pass in here:

```
Gsurf( this )
```

But an `Activity` isn't a context exactly, it *has access* to one - but that's set by the system when you start an `Activity`, and it goes through `onCreate` etc. But if you're not using `CardTransactionUseCase` as an `Activity` that gets displayed, it's just an object you create yourself (e.g. `CardTransactionUseCase()`) then it won't have a `Context` set on it.

That's why you're getting this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

because the context is still **null**

---

If this is what you're doing, then Mike's comment is correct - it shouldn't be an `Activity`, if you need a `Context` then just pass one in.

If you *are* using it as a real `Activity`, then make sure you're not trying to access the `context` until at least `onCreate`. Don't declare any top-level variables or run any `init` code that tries to access it at construction time