# NullPointerException when using Activity as Context

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I got a NullPointerException which appeared strange at first (or rather still does). The corresponding code is:

```kotlin
class Player(
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
    private val ctx: Context
) {
    init {
        Log.d("FOO", ctx.toString())
        Log.d("FOO", ctx.cacheDir.toString())
    }
    ...
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val player = Player(lifecycleScope, this)
    ...
}
```

The log output is:

```
FOO/de.andrekr.android.box.MainActivity@90d5f8e
AndroidRuntime/Shutting down VM
AndroidRuntime/FATAL EXCEPTION: main
               Process: de.andrekr.android.box, PID: 30690
               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.andrekr.android.box/de.andrekr.android.box.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference
```

Note how it prints `de.andrekr.android.box.MainActivity@90d5f8e`, proving that `ctx` is *not* null but then when I call `getCacheDir()` I get the NPE.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104457/kotlin-error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-content-context-android-c/72104635#72104635) that says:

> But an Activity isn't a context exactly, it *has access* to one

So how does this work in Java terms? `Activity extends Context`, doesn't it? How can `ctx` change from being `Activity` to being null? Especially since it's immutable (Kotlin `val`)?

Comment: `Activity` is a `ContextWrapper`, which is just a `Context` that delegates all method calls to another `Context` instance it keeps as a field. It's that field that's null when you try to use `Context` methods in your class's field initializers; it hasn't been set yet by the system. Those particular NPEs are a little confusing at first.

Comment: @MikeM. OMG, you're right, I totally missed the top line of the stack trace which reads `at android.content.ContextWrapper.getCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:273)`. It isn't *my* call that fails, but the delegation. You want to make this an answer or should I?

Comment: Go nuts. I don't do answers atm. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out (thanks Mike M. for your comment) that `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()'` doesn't refer to *my* `ctx.cacheDir.toString()` call but instead to this line from `ContextWrapper`:

```
@Override
public File getCacheDir() {
    return mBase.getCacheDir();
}
```

I simply had missed the top line of the stack trace which reads:

```
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:273)
```